# How to update MVVMCross from 5.1.1 to 5.2.0

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I updated MVVMCross 5.1.1 to 5.2.0 in a sample project (TipCalc) with Android and UWP.
Nuget offered this update an I just updated using VS2017 nuget view.

After this two things happend:The UPW designer tells me that views:MvxWindowsPage doesn't exist in the namespace MvvmCross.Uwp.Views.
So I have no longer a working designer.

Rebuild brings up these warnings

```
...TipCalc.UI.Droid.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.dll(v7.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project(v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
...TipCalc.UI.Droid.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for MvvmCross.Droid.dll (v7.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project(v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
...TipCalc.UI.Droid.csproj : warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for MvvmCross.Platform.Droid.dll (v7.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project(v6.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.
```

Starting it on the emulator crashes the app.
The droid project is set to Marshmellow (6.0).

Does the MVVMCross 5.2 version need Lollipop (7.0) - or did I something wrong when updating?

Comment: Restarting VS fixed the UWP Problem - but Android still exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install the Android 7.0 SDK using the SDK manager. You app should also be set to compile against the latest version, so it should pick this up automatically.

MvvmCross uses the latest Android support libraries, and these use the 7.0 SDK.

Comment: I could change to 7.0 - but I want to target 6.0 since my app should also run on older devices. My problem is if this is "by design" which would mean that if I use the latest version of MVVMCross I can no longer target 6.0 devices...

Comment: Nope - you can use older devices whilst compiling against 7. Set the minimum android version to whatever is the lowest you want to support, compile (target framework) to use latest, and target version to whichever platform you think is most appropriate (i normally just leave it to use the compile version). There's good docs at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/

Comment: thank you for the explanations. I just was confused by two things. First the fact that the update of MvvmCross brought up a higher version of Android - and next the circumstance, that "min / target / compile" is no longer on one page as often seen in blogs / documentation. Instead Compile is on Application tab while Min / target is on the Manifest tab. Anyhow - everthing works fine now!

Comment: MvvmCross technically doesn't use the latest Android support libraries. MvvmCross 5.2 was released after support 25.4.0.2 had been out for a while but MvvmCross 5.2 is still using support 25.3.1.